# Typescript exclude Type from Type

Tags: typescript, types

```
interface First {
  field1: number;
}

interface Second {
  field2: number
}

interface Third extends First, Second {

}

// type Forth = Omit<Third, Second>
// expect Fourth to be { field1: number}
```

With the well know Omit type we can omit properties from a type

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
```

E.g.

```
 Omit<Third, 'field2'> and it will work as the above
```

But the problem is when Second has more than a few fields

Is this achievable? How?

Comment: What's the problem? Use union types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to exclude all the keys of one type from another type, you can use `keyof` as the parameter to `Omit`:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>

interface First {
  field1: number;
}

interface Second {
  field2: number
}

interface Third extends First, Second {

}

type ThirdWithoutSecond = Omit<Third, keyof Second>
```